# should I target the 4.0 framework yet?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I develop a set of .NET components which I sell to developers.
My question is simple .. is it too early to target the 4.0 framework ?
If I target the 4.0 framework, then my components will only work in VS 2010. What is the adoption rate of VS 2010 so far ? Have most developers taken the jump to VS 2010 / 4.0 framework ? 
I have to add that my components do not use feature specific to the 4.0 framework.

Thank you

Comment: you are essentially asking us to make a business decision for you. Surely, you know your market better than we do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal opinion, you should always target the lowest possible version of the framework.

If you are only using 2.0 parts of the framework (eg. no LINQ), then there is no real reason to specifically target 4.0.

As I said, my personal view, but the lower you target it, the more accessible it theoretically is.

Answer (score 2):

Your best answer will come from your customers. If they're not demanding a 4.0 build, I'd stick with 3.5 as your primary target. You should be able to provide a build for 4.0 pretty easily from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use anything .net 4.0 specific, I'd go with older.

.Net 2.0 is definitely a safe bet.